# How to reference an SWT view from a TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I would like to get a reference to a view in my application from my `TitleAreaDialog`.

There are many information to pass to the controls on the `view`. I have created many `getters` and `setters` to handle changes the values, but I still need a reference to the `view` which is not a `static class`.

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find a good example.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what it is you're after (a reference to an instance of your view class that's visible in the workbench), try this:

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow activeBenchWindow = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage[] pages = activeBenchWindow.getPages();
IWorkbenchPage page = pages[0];
IViewPart yourView = page.findView(YourView.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to the TitleAreaDialog in the constructor.